# Unexpected behavior with inactive Changelists in CLion 2023.1.1

Tags: version-control, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am evaluating CLion 2023.1.1, Build #CL-231.8109.222, on Fedora 38 (GNOME). According to [JetBrains' documentation of the active Changelist](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/managing-changelists.html#active-changelist), "all new changes will be automatically placed in this changelist". I am familiar with this feature from IntelliJ IDEA and have always appreciated it as a complement to Git branches.

As a new CLion user, I have noticed that sometimes changes are placed in an inactive changelist instead of the active one, even though I have enabled the "Allow putting changes within one file into different changelists" option in the settings (Version Control/Changelists).

This seems to occur when the modified lines are close to those in the inactive changelist, although not necessarily the same lines.

I created a [demo video to illustrate the issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbbi4riklas3p7g/clion%20puts%20change%20into%20inactive%20changelist.webm?dl=0). I experienced this effect in various scenarious. To reproduce it, here's the procedure I did in the video:

- I created two test changelists A and B and set A as the active changelist.
- I modified a file, and as expected, the changes were assigned to changelist A.
- Next, I made changelist B active and edited the same file at a position that is not adjacent to the previous changes but after some existing code lines. The changes were correctly assigned to changelist B, as expected.
- I continued editing the file, this time modifying lines that followed the edits made in the context of changelist A. However, the changes were unexpectedly assigned to changelist A, even though changelist B was still active.

To verify which changelist the changes were assigned to, I double-clicked the file inside changelist A or B. Note that in the diff view, changes from other changelists are also highlighted, but only those belonging to the current diff are colored on the right side.

I expect the behavior to be consistent with the documentation, which states that all new changes will be automatically placed in the active changelist. In my understanding, "new" refers to the changes made when a particular changelist was active. One could argue that "new" means "in a different code position", but in my view, this would contradict the concept of changelists as I experienced them in IntelliJ IDEA.

Any help or insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:**

I have discovered the root cause of the behavior I initially described in CLion (and, as it turns out, also in IntelliJ IDEA). In the Changelist Settings, there is a checkbox labeled "allow putting changes within one file into different changelists." When this option is disabled (which is the default setting), two additional checkboxes become available:

- "show dialog on attempt to edit file from inactive changelist"
- "highlight files with changelist conflicts"

With these options, you can receive warnings or dialogs when editing files that have already been edited in an inactive changelist.

However, when you enable the "allow putting changes within one file into different changelists" option, the other two checkboxes become disabled, and there is no direct replacement for them. As a result, there is no way to display a warning or dialog when editing lines directly adjacent to lines edited in another changelist. In this case, the changes are silently assigned to the non-active changelist, which seems to contradict the documentation.

I initially believed that IntelliJ IDEA behaved differently, but after further testing, I discovered that it exhibits the same behavior as CLion.